# Не убирается экранирование в JSON ответе

Tags: php, json, экранирование

```
function getRefByUserID($apiMethodParams)
    {
        $retJSON = $this->createDefaultJson();
        if (isset($apiMethodParams))
        {
            $refUserID = $apiMethodParams->UserID;
            $query = "Select * From refs where UserID = " . $refUserID;
            $result = mysqli_query($this->mySQLWorker->connectLink, $query);


            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0)
            {
                while($row=$result->fetch_row())
                {
                    $ref = new Reference($row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4], $row[5], $row[6]);
                    $retJSON->Result = json_encode($ref, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
                }
            }
            else{
                $retJSON->Error = APIConstants::$ERROR_CAN_NOT_ROW;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $retJSON->error = APIConstants::$ERROR_PARAMS;
        }
        return $retJSON;
    }
```

Результат:

```
{"response":{"Result":"{\"ID\":\"3\",\"UserID\":\"42\",\"Type\":\"0\",\"FullName\":\"sdfdvcxvxcv\",\"GroupNumber\":\"420\",\"Count\":\"2\",\"Date\":\"2012-12-19\"}"}}
```

Как убрать лишние слэш?

Comment: А зачем там json_encode?

Comment: Сериализация объекта класса Reference в JSON объект.

Comment: У вас Result является строкой и она экранируется. Проще сначала собрать массив, а потом его закодировать в json.

Comment: здесь **ничего** кодировать не надо

Comment: поиграйся константами из примера по ссылке http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

В этом коде ничего кодировать не надо. Ни сначала, ни потом. И "собирать" никакой массив не надо. Потому что массив тут один и он уже "собран".

Все что здесь надо сделать - это убрать кучу бессмысленного карго культ кода.

```
        if ($row = $result->fetch_row())
        {
            $retJSON->Result = new Reference(...$row);
        } else{
            $retJSON->Error = APIConstants::$ERROR_CAN_NOT_ROW;
        }
```